# Type-assertion panic

Tags: go, type-assertion

I would like to apply Dependency injection on my code so I create every part of it as a service.

```
type BaseService struct {
    Config config.Container
    SQL    *gorm.DB
    Mongo  *mgo.Session
    Logger logger.Logger
}

type BaseInterface interface {
    Set(c config.Container, sq *gorm.DB, m *mgo.Session, l logger.Logger) BaseInterface
}

func (s BaseService) Set(c config.Container, sq *gorm.DB, m *mgo.Session, l logger.Logger) BaseInterface {
    s.Config = c
    s.SQL = sq
    s.Mongo = m
    s.Logger = l
    return s
}

func NewSetupService(c config.Container, s *gorm.DB, m *mgo.Session, l logger.Logger) SetupService {
    return SetupService{}.Set(c, s, m, l).(SetupService)
}
...
...
```

There is the BaseService and every service extend it as the follow:

```
type SetupService struct {
    BaseService
}

type SetupInterface interface {
    Do()
}

func (s SetupService) Do() {
    mongo := s.Mongo.Clone()
    defer mongo.Close()
    mongoDB := mongo.DB(s.Config.Database.Mongo.DB)
...
...
```

But when I call the NewSetupService function I got a panic which is not clear for me. Basically I create a SetupService{} and call the Set function of this struct, am I right? Then why I got this panic:

```
panic: interface conversion: api.BaseInterface is api.BaseService, not api.SetupService [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: api.BaseInterface is api.BaseService, not api.SetupService
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return a `BaseInterface` from a function, the type of the reference is actually `BaseInterface` and not `SetupService`. It is true that `SetupService` does satisfy `BaseInterface`, but that type information is lost when you cast.

What you could do is this:

```
func (s SetupService) Set() SetupService {
  s.BaseService.Set()
  return s
}
```

One thing to note though is that you're not using pointers, so each method call copies the object and state mutations are not preserved. You might want to replace these:

```
func (s SetupService) ...
```

With these:

```
func (s *SetupService) ...
```

**Update**: Why not just avoid returning the result of Set here?

```
s := SetupService{}
s.Set(...)
return s
```

Comment: Go has no concept of inheritance - not sure what you meant by this or I'd edit the answer myself.

Comment: Thank you. It's solved my problem, but I'm sad because of the extra one function/each service.

Comment: @Adrian: We're splitting hairs here, but I'll rephrase so that it is pedantically correct.

Comment: @PumpkinSeed: Added an update which might make your life simpler.